# Pass passphrase to "hg pull"

Tags: bash, ssh, mercurial

I am really confused guys. I am very new to Linux, but still: I am trying to do

```
hg pull ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/repo
```

on a VPS via Paramiko from Python on my laptop. I have already added the public SSH key to Bitbucket and the private one to id_rsa. When I issue the command above manually (in command line), I am asked for the passphrase to my key. For whatever reason it won't accept stdin via Paramiko. So as a workaround I decided to simply do

```
echo 'passphrase\n' | hg pull ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/repo
```

But even in the command line it doesn't work and keeps asking "Enter passphrase for key '/home/droplet/.ssh/id_rsa'". I've also tried

```
hg pull ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/repo <<< 'passphrase\n'
```

Same result. Could you please explain why? I would expect that these commands provide the input that will be used by "hg pull" when it asks for user's input.

Answer (score 0):

You should be good with `sshpass` tool:

```
sshpass -p passphrase hg pull ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/repo
```

Or with storing the key into your `ssh-agent` before (note, that if the agent is not running, you need to start it using `eval $(ssh-agent)`):

```
ssh-add /home/droplet/.ssh/id_rsa
```

then the `hg pull` should not ask for the passphrase for this key.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. The first one fails even in terminal. Can it be due to "The password prompt used by ssh is, however, currently hardcoded into sshpass"? hg pull doesn't show the passphrase prompt but is waiting for something and entering the passphrase doesn't help. (BTW, the host is already added to known hosts.) The second one works in the terminal, but I can't make it work with Parmiko. Maybe need to find out about not closing channels...

Comment: I appreciate the answer BTW. It gives me more directions to read. Maybe you could add a short explanation why the commands from the OP don't work: because ssh *really* wants to see interactive passphrase input, due to security reasons. So some ssh-related tricks are needed to go around this security measure.